# Installer always sets the wrong locale

Tags: 11.04, ubiquity, locale

I always assumed the system locale was set based on chosen time zone, but that doesn't appear to be the case.  I choose Detroit for my time zone (or New York, I've done both), but Ubuntu always sets my locale as en_CA, and points me to a Canadian mirror for apt on a fresh install.

How is locale chosen?  How can I make sure my locale is set to en_US?  Will that get my apt respositories back to a US mirror?

NOTE: I know how to change my locale, my question is specifically about how to make sure it's set properly on install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please file a bug by running `sudo ubuntu-bug ubiquity`?  It should automatically attach the files in `/var/log/installer`. Please be sure to describe the series of steps you went through to produce this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Done. It turns out my timezone was set to Toronto, even though I specifically set it to Detroit during install.  (I also tried New York, same problem)